# ASIFormDataRequest upload progress is not accurate

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, progress, uiprogressview, asiformdatarequest

Iam using    ASIFormDataRequest for uploading and downloading.
The download progress is very accurate and finished when the download finish, but the upload progress jumps from 0 to 1 rapidly even the upload didnt finish yet. Below the upload request and download request

Upload request:

```
uploadRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ImageBUP.aspx",ZsafeapiURL]] :@"POST"];
                [uploadRequest setTag:i];
                [uploadRequest setDelegate:self];
                [uploadRequest setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
                [uploadRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:[self.progressBarArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                [uploadRequest setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
                [uploadRequest setData:[[self.dataToUpload objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"data"] forKey:nil] ;
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"UserID" value:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userID"]];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"Handsettype" value:@"3"];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"ImageName" value:imageName];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"ImagePath" value:@"0"];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"Desc" value:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"platform"]];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"Extension" value:[[self.dataToUpload objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"extension"]];
                [uploadRequest addRequestHeader:@"Size" value:[[self.dataToUpload objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"sizeInByte"]];
                [uploadRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
                [uploadRequest setTimeOutSeconds:500];
                [myQueue addOperation:uploadRequest];


Download request:

      NSString *videoURL=[[self.dataToUpload objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"videoURL"];
                NSString *videoOriginalName=[[self.dataToUpload objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
                NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Videos"];

                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
                NSString *videoPathInApp=[folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoOriginalName];


                downloadRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL] :@"GET"];
                [downloadRequest setDelegate:self];
                [downloadRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:videoPathInApp];
                [downloadRequest setDownloadProgressDelegate:[self.progressBarArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                [downloadRequest setTag:i];
                [downloadRequest setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
                [myQueue addOperation:downloadRequest];
```

am I missing anything ?

Comment: You are aware that ASIHttpRequest is deprecated and no longer maintained by its developer. Also it has known bug in iOS 7 and higher. I would really stress you to switch to another network library.

Comment: you mean afnetworking ?

Comment: `AFNetworking` is my personal choice but there are others.